# how to make a transaction effects(fade, slide, blur) in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, slider

i have a sample html file(with dummy text), and used jquery, see this fiddle -

```
>    [demo][1]
```

when you press prev and next, it shows you prev and next element in a div.

it works perfectly, but i want to animate it, meaning that i want to add a transaction when i press next, like a fade effect or a slide effect, something very attractive.

Can this be achieved with jQuery? If any volunteers help me out, that would be a great honor.

[1]: http://jsfiddle.net/gr8_boi52/dnKWU/ ]

Comment: Look at animate() jquery method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.animate()`, of simple use `.fadeIn()`/`.fadeOut()`. I updated your js code:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('#sentences *').eq(0).addClass('current'); // start by showing the first sentence
    $('#nextBtn, #prevBtn').click(function() {
        var currItem = $('#sentences .current');
        var newItem = ($(this).attr('id') == 'nextBtn') ? currItem.next() : currItem.prev();
        if (newItem.size() > 0) {
            currItem.fadeOut(function() {
                currItem.removeClass('current');
                newItem.addClass('current').fadeIn();
            });
        }
    });
});
```

It's [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sG7DG/)

Answer (score 0):

For fade effect, You can use `.fadeIn()` or `.fadeOut()` in jQuery

See the updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/dnKWU/3/

Comment: wow, it worked perfectly. But why is next button still active after the last sentence is is up. I don't like it when it shows nothing instead of stopping at the last sentence

Comment: awesome!! nice job, exactly what i need.

Comment: why does sentence 2 goes down a little bit? its not really an issue, but if its a minor problem in the code, let me know. If its a major error, then thats okay. I REALLY APPRECIATE YOUR WORK, THANKS

Comment: Its b'coz you applied display 'inline' to the class 'current' and class current is applied to first 'p' when dom ready. See this updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/dnKWU/12/